# How to concatenate every 5 lines if column 2 equal to a certain value?

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I have a file that if the second column has the number 2, I want to concatenate the next 5 lines, for example:

```
67 2
a b c 
a b
0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4
0.3 0.9 0.7 0.1
09 3
b v c
5 6 7 8
78 2
p o p
q d
1.0 0.9 0.8 0.7
0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1
```

The output should be:

```
67 2 a b c a b 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.3 0.9 0.7 0.1
78 2 p o p q d 1.0 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1
```

Comment: That space preceding the  `67` technically puts `67` into col 2.  Is that what you intend? Or are leading spaces to be ignored?

Comment: No, I didn't intend to put that space, it was just a mistake

Comment: `1 2 3 4` has a `2` in the second column so why aren't the 5 lines after that appended to it? What **exactly** is your actual criteria for when to concatenate lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***awk*** solution: To concatenate 5 lines (including *pattern* line) on each encountering the line with `2` in its 2nd column (excepting lines concatenated):

```
awk '$2==2{i=4;tail=$0; while (i-- && (getline nl) > 0) { tail=tail FS nl } print tail}' file
```

The output:

```
67 2 a b c a b 1 2 3 4 0 9 7 1
78 2 p o p q d 0 9 8 7 4 3 2 1
```